# How do I animate a bar chart?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, charts

Is there any easy way to have an animated bar chart (one where the heights of the bars change with time)? I currently have the following code:

```
α := 1/2
β := 1/2
γ := 0
δ := 0
ϵ := 0
ζ := 0
η := 1/2
θ := 1/2
w := 2 Pi

DSolve[{a'[t] == (-2 I*w/3) a[t], b'[t] + c'[t] + e'[t] == 0, 
d'[t] + f'[t] + g'[t] == 0, b'[t] - c'[t] == (I*w/3) (b[t] - c[t]), 
f'[t] - g'[t] == (I*w/3) (f[t] - g[t]), 
b'[t] + c'[t] - 2 e'[t] == (I*w/3) (b[t] + c[t] - 2 e[t]), 
2 d'[t] - f'[t] - g'[t] == (I*w/3) (2 d[t] - f[t] - g[t]), 
h'[t] == (-2 I*w/3) h[t], a[0] == α, b[0] == β, 
c[0] == γ, d[0] == δ, e[0] == ϵ, 
f[0] == ζ, g[0] == η, h[0] == θ}, {a[t], b[t], 
c[t], d[t], e[t], f[t], g[t], h[t]}, t]

Animate[Show[
BarChart[{{Re[a[t]] /. %, Im[a[t]] /. %}, {Re[b[t]] /. %, 
Im[b[t]] /. %}, {Re[c[t]] /. %, Im[c[t]] /. %}, {Re[d[t]] /. %, 
Im[d[t]] /. %}, {Re[e[t]] /. %, Im[e[t]] /. %}, {Re[f[t]] /. %, 
Im[f[t]] /. %}, {Re[g[t]] /. %, Im[g[t]] /. %}, {Re[h[t]] /. %, 
Im[h[t]] /. %}}], BoxRatios -> Automatic], {t, 0, 30}, 
AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False, RefreshRate -> 30]
```

I have 8 differential equations being solved, and the real and imaginary parts of each solution is being plotted, so there are 8x2 bars. Understandably, though, this gives me the error 'BarChart is not a type of graphics'.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance ;)

Comment: There are a surprisingly large number of posts recently where `Show` is unnecessarily used. I'm wondering if these posts all originate from the same classroom and are due to (incorrect) teacher instruction.

Comment: There's a lot of close votes here, but I cannot agree that the mistake is "simple". It's a matter of `Animate` localizing the variable `t`, while the output from `DSolve` has a different `t` in mind. I'm quite sure, a duplicate question (or rather one that points specifically to localization) should be here somewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems.  One is that in your `DSolve` call, you should solve for the functions `{a, b, ...}` instead of the expressions `{a[t], b[t],...}`.  (In my experience, it's almost always better this way.)  The other is that to get the proper list structure for `BarChart`, you should use `First@DSolve[..]` to remove an unnecessary `{}.

```
dsol = First@
   DSolve[{a'[t] == (-2 I*w/3) a[t], b'[t] + c'[t] + e'[t] == 0, 
     d'[t] + f'[t] + g'[t] == 0, 
     b'[t] - c'[t] == (I*w/3) (b[t] - c[t]), 
     f'[t] - g'[t] == (I*w/3) (f[t] - g[t]), 
     b'[t] + c'[t] - 2 e'[t] == (I*w/3) (b[t] + c[t] - 2 e[t]), 
     2 d'[t] - f'[t] - g'[t] == (I*w/3) (2 d[t] - f[t] - g[t]), 
     h'[t] == (-2 I*w/3) h[t], a[0] == α, b[0] == β, 
     c[0] == γ, d[0] == δ, e[0] == ϵ, 
     f[0] == ζ, g[0] == η, h[0] == θ},
    {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}, t];

Animate[
 BarChart[{{Re[a[t]], Im[a[t]]}, {Re[b[t]], Im[b[t]]},
           {Re[c[t]], Im[c[t]]}, {Re[d[t]], Im[d[t]]},
           {Re[e[t]], Im[e[t]]}, {Re[f[t]], Im[f[t]]},
           {Re[g[t]], Im[g[t]]}, {Re[h[t]], Im[h[t]]}} /. dsol,
   PlotRange -> 0.5 {-1, 1}, Frame -> True],
 {t, 0, 30}, AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False, 
 RefreshRate -> 30]
```

[image]

For those with V10.1+ and a fear of braces:

```
Animate[BarChart[ReIm@Through@{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}@t /. dsol, 
  PlotRange -> 0.5 {-1, 1}, Frame -> True], {t, 0, 30}, 
 AnimationRate -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False, RefreshRate -> 30]
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @turbodiesel4598  You're welcome.

Comment: +1, please consider `(ReIm[#@t] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h}) /. dsol`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, and my own version.  For some reason I don't like `ReIm`.  Maybe when they get to 30000 functions in WL, I'll feel more friendly to these trivial extensions of the language.  (Also it's less work to copy/paste/replace than to think.)

Answer (score -3):

```
barData = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {5}];
Manipulate[
 BarChart[barData[[i]]],
 {i, 1, 5, 1}]
```

or

```
Animate[
 BarChart[barData[[i]]],
 {i, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Comment: Maybe you meant this as a joke, but I don't see how this helps the OP solve the problem.  (I guess it answers the title of the question, but not the body.)

Comment: The question poser seemed to know how to get the raw data to be plotted (from the differential equations) but was asking about animating a bar graph.  My answer addresses everything the poser asked, and was listed in the title.

Comment: The OP does not have data to be plotted, not like `barData`.  They have expressions that evaluate to numerical values.  (That's the difference I see.)